# Pod Install fails on Teamcity Build Server

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods, teamcity

So after installing Cocoapods on an OSX Build server with `sudo gem install cocoapods` I can now successfully run the command `pod --version` on my OSX terminal.

[image]

All good. However, a Teamcity build configuration which needs to run the command `pod install ..` can't, as it reports the error

> /Users/andrew/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script8915166564844625540: line 5: pod: command not found

I'm sure its a Teamcity permissions / user / environment variable issue but don't know what to search for.

[image]

Any pointers?

Comment: Is `pod` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: It is ... What I have discovered is that Teamcity sees a different $PATH than the local server. Even though teamcity is running as same user. I have solved the problem temporarily by fully qualifying the path to pod e.g. `$HOME/software/ruby/bin/pod install`

Comment: I got this issue... Even if I set the fully qualifying path :/ Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: if I did, I can't remember, sorry.